# CopyOnwriteArrayList Java concurrency

Tags: java, concurrency

Добрый день!
коллекция из сабжа , ка кизвестно, перед внесением изменений , делает копию массива, а после - просто присваивает ее заново в массив.
Но возникает вопрос.
Если 2 потока одновременно сделали себе копии, произвели изменения в них, а потом сохранили . То в этом случае массив одного из потоков наложится на другой и мы не увидим их изменения.
Какой тогда в этом случае мы получаем выйгрыш в безопасности?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Два потока не могут сделать это одновременно, т.к. операции копирования и присваивания выполняются в критической секции. См. для примера метод `add` указанной коллекции.

Comment: моя вина, пропустил (